# insert a key => value pair in a PHP associative array at a given position

Tags: php, foreach

as mentionned in the title i'd like to add at a given position a key => value pair after checking with an if statement wether the value not empty && > 1.

The problem is when I add my key => value in the $content array the pair is added at the end of my array. I want the pair to be added after the 'version' key.

here is my foreach loop and a piece of the resulting array:

```
 foreach ($nodeChildrenResult['hits']['hits'] as $child) {
    
                    if ($child['_type'] === 'folder') {
    
                        $content[] = array(
    
                            'id'      => intval($child['_id']),
                            'type'    => $child['_type'],
                            'name'    => $child['_source']['node']['basename']
    
                        );
                    }else {
    
                        $content[] = array(
    
                            'id'          => intval($child['_id']),
                            'type'        => $child['_type'],
                            'name'        => $child['_source']['node']['name'],
                            'filename'    => $child['_source']['node']['basename'],
                            'extension'   => $child['_source']['node']['extension'],
                            'date'        => [
                                "import"  => $child['_source']['node']['date']['import'],
                                "update"  => $child['_source']['node']['date']['update']
                            ],
                            'version'     => $child['_source']['node']['version'],
                            'locked'      => (isset($child['_source']['node']['locked']) &&  $child['_source']['node']['locked'] == 1) ? true : false,
                            'link'        => (in_array($child['_source']['node']['extension'], $allowedExtensionForCollab) ) ? [ 'collab' => "/v2/MODULES/COLLAB/?node=".intval($child['_id'])] : [],
                            'workflow'    => $results[intval($child['_id'])]
    
                        );
    
                        if (!empty($child['_source']['node']['pageCount']) and $child['_source']['node']['pageCount'] > 1) {
                         
                            $content['pageCount'] = $child['_source']['node']['pageCount'];
    
                        }
```

```
    3 (10) => [
            id => 3,
            type => 'file',
            name => 'tomates',
            filename => 'tomates.png',
            extension => 'png',
            date (2) => [
                import => '20201019T122023+0200',
                update => '20201019T142127+0200'
            ],
            version => 2,
            locked => true,
            link (1) => [
                collab => '/v2/MODULES/COLLAB/?node=3'
            ],
            workflow (3) => [
                0 (2) => [
                    step (2) => [
                        id => 1,
                        name => 'prétraitement'
                    ],
                    status (3) => [
                        id => 1,
                        name => 'resizing',
                        color => '#c80078'
                    ]
                ],
                1 (2) => [
                    step (2) => [
                        id => 2,
                        name => 'validation'
                    ],
                    status (3) => [
                        id => 4,
                        name => 'validation',
                        color => '#488818'
                    ]
                ],
                2 (2) => [
                    step (2) => [
                        id => 3,
                        name => 'impression'
                    ],
                    status (3) => [
                        id => 5,
                        name => 'en impression',
                        color => '#c80078'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
             pageCount => 3
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. array_filter does the job if null :

```
$content[] = arry_filter( array(
    
                            'id'          => intval($child['_id']),
                            'type'        => $child['_type'],
                            'name'        => $child['_source']['node']['name'],
                            'filename'    => $child['_source']['node']['basename'],
                            'extension'   => $child['_source']['node']['extension'],
                            'date'        => [
                                ...
                           'version'     => $child['_source']['node']['version'],
                           'pageCount'   => (!empty($child['_source']['node']['pageCount']) && $child['_source']['node']['pageCount'] > 1) ? $child['_source']['node']['pageCount'] : null,
```

Comment: * if 'pageCount' key is null here

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short if after you assign the version key. If the condition is false just set it to null.

```
<?php

$pageCount = 123;

$a[] = [
    'version' => '1.0',
    'pageCount' => (!empty($pageCount) && $pageCount > 1) ? $pageCount : null,
    'name' => 'Peter'
];

var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes I forgot to mention. If pagecount is less than one I don't want to display the key 'pageCount'. That's the crux of the problem here.